# How to force a casing convention in Auth.js / NextAuth.js Drizzle adapter?

Tags: next-auth, drizzle

Auth.js / NextAuth.js [mentioned that](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapters#rdbms-naming-convention) most of the database adapter have a dedicated documentation section on how to force a casing convention. Unfortunately I don't find this for [Drizzle database adapter](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/drizzle).

May I know if it is possible to use snake_case formatting for all the column names when using Drizzle databae adapter?